# Duplicate record to keep copy of original

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im working on a project that allows users to submit and vote on changes.  However I want to keep a version of the original so users can view it and see the difference between the original and what has been voted on to change.  What Im wondering is what is the best way to do this?

I was originally thinking of creating the recipe twice and making a reference to one of the ids in the other as the original, but wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

i think there a many ways to do it:-

1. Using single table,for every new recipe record,you may add a version column and on create ,update it every time.so you just need to compare current recipe and current recipe -1 record .
2. Using two tables,first table will store every recipes created,other table will  just store last recipe id of that user(user.recipes.last) after every new recipe is created using `has many through` model.So for example:-

   user has_many :recipe_copies, :dependent => :destroy
   user has_many :recipe through: :recipe_copies

so for every new record in `recipes` table,you can **ADD** **new row** in `recipes_copy` table using `user.recipes.last.id` and `New recipe` id and store it in copy table.

such as

```
recipe_copies:- previous_recipe,recipe_id,user_id
      recipes:- name,user_id,description,active...etc
```

Hope it helps